# Angular 12 Httpclient jsonp - how to pass custom callback parameter?

Tags: typescript, geolocation, jsonp, angular12

Angular 12 - Httpclient jsonp - how to pass custom callback parameter?

Here is the full app -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2zg5yt?file=src/app/geolocation.service.ts

**geolocation-service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeolocationService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getLocation(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .jsonp<any>('https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp', 'callback')
      .pipe();
  }
}
```

Gives the following error:

[image]

How to change the callbackparam value to be - `https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp?callback=callback`
but angular is defaulting it to `https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp?callback=ng_jsonp_callback_1`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is not an issue in Angular Httpclient jsonp implementation. Instead, it is an issue in the `https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp`. which does not dynamically update the callback function name.

The same example works like a charm with `http://ip-api.com/json`

Comment: I think this is the actual Angular/JSONP answer across the board. Submitting a MailChimp form worked one time then never again.